# Python program to count characters that fall between ! and 2 ##

Tags: python-3.x

i have a problem with this question:
You have a string containing !, # and small alphabets a-z. You have to escape each character that follows an ! and lies between 2 # symbols. [Treat odd # as ( and even # as ) ] You have to print out how many alphabets will be escaped.

Input Format

Input will be one line containing the string sequence

Constraints

n = len(string_seq)
1 < n < 1000

Output Format

Output will be a single integer

```
Sample Input 0

#!a!b#c!d
Sample Output 0

2

Sample Input 1

##bc!a#
Sample Output 1

0
```

Now this code clears 6 out of 9 test cases but i am not able to understand how to make it clear all the test cases i have tried many ways. My suspision is the test caeses might be wrong. Can someome help me tell me if the question is wrong or the test cases is wrong or my code is wrong and if my code is wrong please help me rectify it. Thank You.

```
def escape(str1):
counter=0
if(str1.count('!')%2==1):
    return '0'
for a,b in enumerate(str1):
    if(b=='#'):
        if(97<=ord(str1[a+1])<=122):
            if(str1.index('#')<a+1<len(str1)-str1[::-1].index('#')):
                counter+=1
return counter
```

str1=input()
print(escape(str1))

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this code works for all your cases so i make my solution better..

```
case='#h!a!h#gh#!d##ghj#'
cnt=0
temp=''
flag=False
for c in case:
    if c=='#':
        if flag:
            #print(temp)
            tl=temp.split('!')
            if len(tl)>1:
                #print(tl)
                #tl=list(filter(('').__ne__, tl))
                #print(tl)
                cnt+=len(tl)-1

            temp=''
            flag=False
        else:
            flag=True
    else:
        temp+=c
print(cnt)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but your code also cleared the sample test case and failed the rest.

Comment: Can you gimme me more test cases to see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
def escape(str1):
  i=0
  counter=0
  final_counter=0
  condition1=False
  while(i!=len(str1)):
    if(str1[i]=='#' and condition1==False):
      condition1=True
      i+=1
    elif(str1[i]=='#' and condition1==True):
      condition1=False
      final_counter+=counter
      counter=0
      i+=1
    elif(condition1==True):
      if(str1[i]=='!'):
        i+=1
        if(97<=ord(str1[i])<=122):
          counter+=1
          i+=1
      else:
        i+=1
    else:
      i+=1
  return final_counter
```

I hope this helps.
I think that the problem asks you for the following conditions to increase your counter:
First you can start counting when a '#' appears, otherwise you can't start counting.
Then when you find a letter after a '!' (e.g !a) you increase your counter.
Finally, if another "#" you accumulate everything in your final counter which you are going to print.

Confirm me if this is correct with all your test cases.

Comment: thanks man for ur help but ur code only passed the sample test cases and failed the rest .Thank you for the help though

Comment: Could you give me more test cases to check which ones failed?